# Does 6DOF robot arm + linear rail = 7DOF arm?

Tags: robotic-arm

Assume we have a 6DOF manipulator, take [UR5](https://www.universal-robots.com/media/50588/ur5_en.pdf) as an example. Does adding a [linear rail](https://www.kuka.com/en-us/products/robotics-systems/robot-periphery/linear-units), on which the robot sits, add a 7th DOF to the system, making it equivalent to a 7DOF manipulator? Any caveats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct.
Adding an external axis results in 6+1=7 DOF.

Caveats...the same as for any redundant system

- solving IK requires a more complex approach (and then path/trajectory planning also)
- precision/repeatability/accuracy can be affected if the external axis has a worse precision/repeatability//accuracy
- same goes for dynamic performance
- technical compatibility issues might arise (depending on how the external axis is controlled and what communication protocols are available at the robot controller)